# How exchanges generate transactions for all cryptocurrencies and send it to their network nodes?

Tags: bitcoin, wallet, cryptocurrency

This is an important question for me, I know some Bitcoin wallets like blockchain.info are a Full Node,
but exchanges which support so many coins, how do they create transactions per cryptocurrency? do they have a full node client for per cryptocurrency?

Just Bitcoin needs 170 GB space disk!

Are exchanges using third-party servers and apis?

Comment: Good question - but it might be a little off topic here. Consider asking on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/. Questions about cryptocurrencies in general are welcome there too according to their Help Center.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer, but my question related to transaction structure and full node wallet

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not a programming question. You may be able to get help on our sister site, [bitcoin.se].

Answer (score 0):

From an exchange's security view an exchange would better trust their own clients hosted within their network. Exchanges better take it serious because it might be the most vulnerable point when dealing with cryptocurrencies.

Remember when Ripple's S2 server(public) went down around Dec 2017. Major exchanges might've learned a lesson there.

It was not Ripple's fault but most people blamed Ripple for that back in the day. It really was exchanges' fault. On contrary Rippled is quite costly to run compared to Bitcoin or Ethereum full nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.Exchanges run full node of every coin they are listing. I am part of an exchange, and thus, I know it. We have 15 daemons running on a 32GB / 2 TB / 9 vCPU server.

Costs are high, but security first.